# Forward domain to another one without redirection, Two domains One content

Tags: .htaccess

i've two domains

1 - emiddy-hosting.com

2 - isellsoftwares.com

i was using Cpanel parked domain service to forward ( isellsoftwares.com ) to ( emiddy-hosting.com ) [ without redirection ]

but now, i moved ( isellsoftwares.com ) to new server, and i can't use this service!

i want .. if you went to ( isellsoftwares.com ) you see the content of ( emiddy-hosting.com )

is there anyway to do it by htaccess or apache or anything? ( the both servers are mine )

Note i've tried rewrite proxy by htaccess and it was working so fine, but it take much bandwith, is anyway else?

## Again, The goal is, i want if you open ( isellsoftwares.com ) , you see the homepage of ( emiddy-hosting.com )

Answer (score 0):

You can point both domains to the same Public IP address. However, if you're using virtual hosts, you need to add the old domain name as an alias under the VirtualHost. You can do this in apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine On
ServerName myserver.com
ServerAlias myoldserver.com
```

Or probably for your case:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName  emiddy-hosting.com
ServerAlias  isellsoftwares.com
```

You can even achieve this with different combinations of IP addresses and FQDN using VirtualHosts. More examples: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html